# Determine which instructions are supported by the processor

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) is able to determine the instructions your processor supports. For example the following link shows these instructions:

`MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T`

Is there a way to accomplish this using `.NET`, `WMI` or some other technology?

Comment: Not natively. There might be some stuff exposed via WMI.

Comment: This question makes completely no sense with the [c#] tag.  Using boutique instructions requires writing assembly.  A jitter writes it for you, it is out of your control.

Comment: @HansPassant I think it makes sense to have the C# tag - the poster is looking for a way to achieve this using C#/.NET. I actually had a similar need earlier this year (although I ended up writing the solution in assembly). It not impossible that someone developed a managed library that provides this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `kernel32.dll` you have the function [IsProcessorFeaturePresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which you can [pInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.isprocessorfeaturepresent).

**Edit**
Regarding `EM64T` extended instruction set, this is only available on x64 platforms so you can check which type of CPU is present through WMI:

```
public static bool IsEM64TSupported()
{
  ManagementObject mo;
  mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'");
  ushort i = (ushort) mo["Architecture"];

  return i == 9;
}
```

But since EM64T instructions are not available in 32-bit operating systems you'll need to check that too.

Comment: Using the pInvoke link you sent me - I am having trouble finding EM64T

Comment: @Aducci this is probably because that site is automatically generated (and it looks like from an older version of the MSDN site). pInvoke is a PowerShell wrapper for C++ code from what I can tell. The script is located at http://poshcode.org/1409 . More details can be found here, http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/ .

Comment: @dragon788: Umm... No... pInvoke is a method to execute unmanaged function in managed code.